Is gRPC case insensitive when mapping methods?
Edit: Overlooked the output of the file - answered my own question below.
Let's say we have a node.js project with a proto file:
syntax = "proto3";

package bookstore;

service Bookstore {
  rpc AddBook (AddBookRequest) returns (AddBookResponse) {}
}

And a server file server.js:
// Implement the AddBook RPC method
function addBook(call, callback) {
 ...
}

...


function main() {
  const server = new grpc.Server();
  
  server.addService(bookstoreProto.Bookstore.service, {
    addBook: addBook,  
  });
 ...

}
...


How does addBook (lowercase a) know to map to AddBook (uppercase a)? The compiled proto file has a line indicating requestType: bookstore_pb.AddBookRequest, which has a capital A.
I'm confused as how the lowercase method somehow maps to the uppercase proto definition.

Looks like the generated .js file from the .proto file actually outputs the method in lowercase.
  addBook: {
    path: '/bookstore.Bookstore/AddBook',
    requestStream: false,
    responseStream: false,
    requestType: bookstore_pb.AddBookRequest,
    responseType: bookstore_pb.AddBookResponse,
    requestSerialize: serialize_bookstore_AddBookRequest,
    requestDeserialize: deserialize_bookstore_AddBookRequest,
    responseSerialize: serialize_bookstore_AddBookResponse,
    responseDeserialize: deserialize_bookstore_AddBookResponse,
  },

